# Custom field displayed based on author node

Tags: entities, nodes

I have a website for ads. In addition the user will have opportunity to make his ad as a VIP ad.

When the user creates a new ad, down bellow will be displayed a field "Make your ad VIP" and after clicking on that button it will popup a description. 
This field is created as custom field with Display suite, but I want to make visible only on node author.

The idea is only user that is author of the node can see that field "Make your ad VIP".

The module "Field permissions" cannot control this custom field.

EDIT:

The field name is "adding_make_vip", the custom module is "custom_alter" and this is the code that I've tried:

```
<?php

function custom_alter_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
  global $user;
  if ($op == 'view' && !empty($entity) && $field['field_name'] == 'adding_make_vip') {

   // $entity will be the node,so check node author with current user.
   if($entity->uid == $user->uid) {
      return TRUE;
    } 
   else {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately it didn't hide the field for anonymous users and users that aren't authors of the node.

Answer (score 0):

How about implementing [hook_field_access()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7) in your custom module.

This hook takes operation edit/view as parameters and returns access to the user for the operations.As a sample code

```
function MYMODULE_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
  global $user;
  if ($op == 'view' && !empty($entity) && $field['field_name'] == 'your_field_name') {

   // $entity will be the node,so check node author with current user.
   if($entity->uid == $user->uid) {
      return TRUE;
    } 
   else {
    return FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've edited my thread. Please check it out.

Comment: codes are not test did you check what's their inside $entity is the cndition check if($entity->uid == $user->uid) appropriate ?also did you cleared your caches

Comment: Yes, I've already cleared my caches. I'm not sure how to check inside $entity with the condition check if($entity->uid == $user->uid)

Comment: @user2519032 if you have devel installed you can check with this code dpm($entity); inside MYMODULE_field_access()

Comment: I've tried with krumo($entity), but there are bunch of (Object) stdClasses and I didn't find theme_breadcrumb() there.

Comment: @user2519032 my bad that was wrong window you do not have to look for any theme_breadcrumb(), just check if you see any uid inside the object and if it is accessible $entity->uid or not

Comment: I still didn't find a way how to set that field to be visible only for a node author. Also the whole idea is, if the user decided to make the ad as VIP, the field would be hidden after that.